# Scaling iframe to fit properly

Tags: html, css, iframe

So I am using an iFrame in my [website](http://dylanapp.weebly.com) to display a video and I put it in a div to allow for resizing on mobile sties and just to make it more responsive etc. However now, if the monitor is small, the content below the iframe is cut off.

Here is the code for the iframe:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/132695239?badge=0" width="960" height="540" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<style>
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
    padding-top: 25px;
    height: 0;
}
.wrapper iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
</style>
```

If anyone can see anything that may cause this behaviour then I would love to know.

Thanks

---

Edit:
Here is the code for the div that I am trying to scale. The width doesn't change as the page is scaled down and thus the height also does not change.
Any ideas?

```
<style>.embed-container { position: relative; padding-bottom: 56.25%; height: 0; overflow: hidden; max-width: 100%; } .embed-container iframe, .embed-container object, .embed-container embed { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; }</style><div class='embed-container'><iframe src='http://player.vimeo.com/video/66140585' frameborder='0' webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe></div>
```

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but you might take a look at http://embedresponsively.com/

Comment: @bmurauer thanks for the suggestion but it basically does the same thing and the problem isn't solved. I can't scroll down.

Comment: Are you wanting to have just the video display on a small screen? Or everything including the title?

Comment: @NateW I would like to have everything display on it however if the user has to scroll vertically then that wouldn't be the end of the world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that your wrapper div `.splash-page .main-wrap` is set to `position: absolute;` and `overflow-y: hidden;` this doesn't allow the div to grow to fit all your content.

If you change your CSS to include something like this:

```
.splash-page .main-wrap {
  overflow-y: visible;
  position: relative;
}
```

It will allow the div to grow to accommodate all your content.

You also could wrap the whole thing in a media query if you just wanted to target a specific width.

```
@media all and (min-width: 1001px) {
  ...
}
```

Currently you'll also have a duplicating background issue because your using `.wsite-background` on both a div and your body tag. If you remove this class from your body tag, it should look better.

Comment: Thanks, I had just discovered that in my code a few minutes ago but will mark as correct for other users on here.

Comment: Would you have any idea how to scale the div which is displaying the iframe? I will add div code above.

Comment: @dwinnbrown your iframe is acting responsive for me... (Safari and Chrome tested) What browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using safari. It is responsive to width but not to heigh - that is my problem

Answer (score 0):

Your iframe has a fixed with. 
Try using width="100%" instead of width="960"